# How Performance Animate Scroll position Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

Hello i Have this problem in a Bootstrap page:

.
.
.

`<a id="godown1">go!</a>`

`<a id="godown2">go!</a>`

`<a id="godown3">go!</a>`

.
.
.
.
.
.

`<div id="goit1"></div>`

`<div id="goit2"></div>`

`<div id="goit3"></div>`

.
.
.
Code next

```
    <script>       
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#godown1").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit1").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
        });
    </script>
    <script>       
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#godown2").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit2").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
        });
    </script>
    <script>       
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#godown3").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit3").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
        });
    </script>
```

That code would have to add in the script?. It turns out that when I press one of these buttons and it automatically drops in a good way.

But when I'm already in place that I want and I press another button containing this animation the animation is repeated again.

This makes it look not very pleasing to the eye.

I can support? Thanks people!

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue..  Maybe you can share your complete html and explain what to do to see the problem.  The only thing I can see is that if you are are close to `goit1` and then click on `godown1` then it takes a long time to move a short ways down.. Is that your issue?

Comment: how send you the link in private

Comment: You could send the link to my email which is located on my profile.

Comment: Thanks. Really i don't see it su email in this link: http://stackexchange.com/users/1009381/trevor or this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1022305/trevor

Comment: hmm okay it's:  trevordowdle@gmail.com

Comment: take a look at my answer.  Let me know if it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your `link` I believe what you are looking for is to only run the animation if the `.blogfootspace child div's` are hidden.

You can combine your code into one `script` and `document ready` function:

Try this:

```
<script>       
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#godown1").click(function() {
            if(!$('.bloqsfootspace div').hasClass('in'))   
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit1").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
        $("#godown2").click(function() {
            if(!$('.bloqsfootspace div').hasClass('in'))
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit2").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
        $("#godown3").click(function() {
            if(!$('.bloqsfootspace div').hasClass('in'))
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#goit3").offset().top}, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

You'll need to change the `godown` and `godoit` to match your code but the `.bloqsfootspace` should stay the same.